# How can I remove specified terms from filename when reading list?

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I am at the very beginning of this phase of a personal project. I have a large number of video files liberally strewn with terms like "1980p", "webrip" and such that I would like to remove.

Easy enough with perl rename from the command line, or it can be done using a renamer with a GUI, but the draw back is that every time you change directories or start a new session you end up inputting the same information over and over and over again.

First - I am using zsh.
Second - I can successfully convert dots, spaces, dashes, etc., to underscores so there are no white spaces in the file/folder names.

Third - I convert all file/folder names to lower case to simplify the task.

Fourth - Either I am doing something wrong or recursion in the shell can be hit or miss, so I'm going folder by folder.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while read i
do
my $i=$(echo $i)
find . -iname "*$i*" rename 's/"$i"//' {} \;
done < /home/terry/.local/bin/Persistent_File_Renamer/persistent_data.txt
```

Gives me the "Global" warning.

I found this one, but it just closes the terminal.

```
if [ $# != 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 input-file"
    exit 1
else
    infile=$1
fi

exec 3< /home/terry/.local/bin/Persistent_File_Renamer/persistent_data.txt

until [ $done ]
do
    read <&3 myline
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        done=1
        continue
    fi
    # process file data line-by-line
    # in here ...
    rename 's/"$myline"//' ./"*$myline*"
done

echo "The End"
```

I'm not a noob, but I'm at wits end here. I have no preference as to method as long as I end up with a re-usable, editable, new-line-ending list.

Thank you.

Comment: That first code snippet looks like a mix between Perl and shell script. Which language were you _intending_ to write that code in?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `zsh`, there's no need for perl `rename`. `zsh`'s `zmv` is as powerful and more reliable.

```
autoload -Uz zmv
strings_to_remove=(
  ${(f)"$(<~/.local/bin/Persistent_File_Renamer/persistent_data.txt)"}
) &&
  zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${${(L)2//[. _-]##/_}//(${(~j[|])strings_to_remove})}'
```

Where:

- `${(f)"$(<file)"}` splits the contents of the file on newline discarding empty lines, here to assign to an array.
- `zmv` renames all the files matching the `(**/)(*)` pattern (any non-hidden file in any level of non-hidden directories), to the expansion of the code in the second argument, depth-first.
- `${(L)2}` turns `$2` (which here captures the basename of the file) to lowercase.
- `${var//[. _-]##/_}`  replaces sequences of 1 or more `_`, `.`, `-` or space characters to 1 `_`.
- `${(~j[|])array}` `j`oins the elements of the array with `|`, but with `~`, that `|` is considered a wildcard operator instead of a literal `|`.

Remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy.

Note that because it replaces all strings at once, if you have `strings_to_remove=(worst bad)` and a filename called `wobadrst.txt`, it will be replaced to `worst_txt`, with the `worst` not removed. Same would happen with your approach.

With the `rename` from perl's `File::Rename`, assuming UTF-8 encoded file names, you could do something similar with

```
find . -depth ! -name . -print0 |
  LIST=~/.local/bin/Persistent_File_Renamer/persistent_data.txt \
  PERL_UNICODE=S rename -n -0 -d '
    use vars qw($pattern);
    BEGIN {
      open LIST, "<", $ENV{LIST} or die "$ENV{LIST}: $!\n";
      chomp(my @strings_to_remove = grep {!/^$/} <LIST>);
      our $pattern = join "|", map {qr{\Q$_\E}} @strings_to_remove;
    }
    s/[_ .-]+/_/g;
    $_ = lc $_;
    s/$pattern//g'
```

In any  case you don't want to embed the expansion of your shell variables into the perl code, that would be a command injection vulnerability. You can pass data to the perl script via the environment like we do here for the `$ENV{LIST}` file.

Comment: Took a short break. I stuck this in a basic for loop, but no luck, to I tried this

Comment: @Terry, that's meant to be used as is, not in a loop. In which way does it not work?

Comment: Stephan: Took a short break. I stuck this in a basic for loop, but no luck, to I tried this  --f=harry_potter_and_the_prisoner_of_azkaban_2004_bdrip_720p.mkv; ${(f)"$(<~/Desktop/data.txt)"}
) &&
  zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${${(L)2//[. _-]##/_}//(${(~j[|])strings_to_remove})}'
zsh: parse error near `)'
I don't have the skills to figure this out. A bit more help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: @Terry, that's not the code shown in my answer.

Comment: Oh, I started a new list. Path is correct. Do I need to do anything special to the list like quoting. It is one term per line and each starts with an underscore

Comment: Ooops, you are correct. I magnified the text to see that I didn't scroll far enough up. I did try you code, however, with no luck. Let me play with it a while to see if the problem is on my end.

Comment: Stephan: I don't know if it's my depression or my A.D.D, but it worked perfectly after I removed -n. My deepest thanks to you.

Comment: Stephane: I copied and pasted your code. The dry run showed no errors so I removed the -n and ran it and it wenr straight to the cursor prompt. ls showed no change in the names. I think I know the problem, I believe I tested your code on a really old lappie I have. A few months I  tried kvm on this thing and still haven't resolved all the issues. I flashed the BIOS, and it helped a  bit. I am now going to try your code on the old one. If I works the way I think it will, I'll be loolking for a new lappie.

Comment: Stephane, your code worked perfectly on my old laie so yes, I am now in the market for a new one. In the meantime I ren rename on this one and encode on the other. Mark this one a success. Thanks.